# Django multiply calculated days field with float column

Tags: python, django, database, date

In my DB I had two date field, then I calculated the difference between those two dates using

```
.annotate(delay=F('date_1') - F('date_2'))
```

Now i have to multiply this delay with another column in database

```
F('delay')*F('amount')
```

But getting errors, also tried by appending days still doesn't work

```
.annotate(a=Sum(F('delay')*F('amount')))
```

'Delay' is difference between dates and amount is the column present in table which has float data type.

Comment: But it does not make much sense, since you did not specify a *unit*. In what should the `delay` be measured? Seconds, days?

Comment: The delay be measured in days. or where should I specify here .annotate(delay=F('date_1') - F('date_2'))

Comment: @BarsmansvapsFriends what error are you getting?